# Saving data in ".t7" format with python

Tags: python, torch

Is there any possible way to save data in ".t7" format with python?

".t7" is the serialization format, which can be opened by lua torch. However, when I save my data in pickle with python with ".t7" at the end of the naming, it does not work.

I have  been searching through internet, but I could not find out any working answer.

Answer (score 0):

there is currently no such converter but there is a workaround. What you can do is convert pyTorch model to Caffe model and from Caffe to Torch (lua) model. [Here](https://github.com/ysh329/deep-learning-model-convertor) is the table of converters by framework.